# How can I load multiple controller factories and pass control on to the next one?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller-factory

I've created a generic controller factory to load entities from the database by parsing out the url:

```
entity/products/123456.htm
```

However, I'd like to be able to load an actual controller if the entity is not found, or to override the default entity behavior if necessary by creating a physical controller, instead of a "virtual" one created by the URL pattern.

Right now, in global.asax.cs I'm doing:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(EntityControllerFactory));
```

How can I, either in `EntityControllerFactory`, or here in `global.asax.cs`, pass control on to another factory, in the event that I'd like MVC's default controller/action scheme to take over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a composite `IControllerFactory` implementation:

```
public class EntityControllerFactory : IControllerFactory {
    private IControllerFactory defaultFactory = new DefaultControllerFactory();

    public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName) {
        if(needsCustomLogic) {
            // do your custom logic here and return appropriate result
        } else {
            return defaultFactory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
        }
    }

    // same for the other methods on IControllerFactory
}
```

This works because by default the value of `ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory()` is an instance of `DefaultControllerFactory`.

You might also consider making your factory more future-proof (in case a new version of MVC starts returning a different type from `GetControllerFactory`; unlikely but it could happen) by getting the default instance and passing it into your factory:

```
// in Global.asax
var defaultFactory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetFactory(new EntityControllerFactory(defaultFactory));
```